# constrain dragging to one axis with native HTML5 Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I realize this can be done when using javascript to do the dragging and dropping, but I need to do with while using HTML5's native DnD capability. Is this even possible?

Comment: So you want the thing being dragged to follow a purely horizontal or purely vertical trajectory?

Comment: exactly. Several javascript or jquery only plugins have this (when sorting a list for example), but I'm specifically looking to recreate this effect with HTML5's native DnD.